# A Double Integral For Calculus I

Tags: calculus, geometry

I stumbled upon this questions and really messed around with it for more than half an hour but did not get any where. I checked back and forth and do not think I copied the question incorrectly.

**Question:**   Evaluate the double integral:   $\displaystyle \int_{1}^{2} \int_{\frac{1}{y}}^{y} (x^2+y^2)dxdy$ by using the substitution: $x = \frac{u}{v}, y = uv$.

I drew the "region" bounded by the limits of the integral in both $xy$ and $uv$ coordinates but still don't see the "rectangle" that is supposed to come out.

Comment: $z=x^2+y^2$ is a 3D paraboloid. Where you look for rectangles?

Comment: While visualizing a function often is useful, in this case pure calculus method is enough.

Comment: Yes, $z = x^2+y^2$ is a paraboloid in space. But I was talking about the region on the ground where we integrate.

Comment: To solve the first integral you consider the plane $x=constant$ The intersection of this plane with a paraboloid is not a rectangle.

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't this just be $\int_1^2\int_{1/y}^y(x^2+y^2)dxdy=\int_1^2\frac{y^3}{3}+y^3-(\frac{3}{y^3}+y) dy$?

In doing so we're treating the inner integral as simplifying the area in a sense to something of a single variable. If I did the algebra correctly after full evaluation the integral should equal $\frac{263}{24}$.

Comment: I could have gone in the same direction as you did, but it ask specifically for the substitution $x = \frac{u}{v}, y = uv$.

Comment: I'm sorry, I totally missed that part!